# GRASS: Modules tab has white background making text unvisible

Tags: grass-gis, linux

GRASS: Modules tab has white background making text unvisible.

[image]

Operating system:

```
ID_LIKE="opensuse suse"
VERSION_ID="20220303"
PRETTY_NAME="openSUSE Tumbleweed"
```

Any tips to fix this?

Grass 7.8.0

Comment: Please edit and add the GRASS GIS version. Seems to be G7?

Comment: I have the same problem in Debian (11) Bullseyes. I'm using Adwaita-dark theme in Debian. Researching about I found something about wxPython aren't using the theme colors for Grass Layer Manager background. I understand what it's mean, but my knowledge is litle to solve it.